# Somas valores JS

Tags: javascript

Duas coisas.

Uma preciso somar os 3 valores, mas está retornando NaN.

```
$('#valor').blur(function(){
   var valor = $("input[name=valor]").val();
   var descontos = $("input[name=descontos]").val();
   var juros = $("input[name=juros]").val();

   valor_cobrado = (parseFloat(valor) - parseFloat(descontos)) + parseFloat(juros);
   $("#valor_cobrado").val(parseFloat(valor_cobrado));
```

Nem sempre descontos ou juros estão preenchidos no form.

E outra pergunta é, como declaro declaro mais campos no blur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está retornando NaN porque se algum dos campos estiver vazio o `parseFloat` não consegue converter *null* em número, causando erro na soma dos valores, já que o JavaScript não irá conseguir somar um número com *null*.

Você pode colocar um operador `||` para que se um dos campos estiver vazio, o valor do campo assuma `0`, evitando o NaN:

```js
$('#valor').blur(function(){
   var valor = $("input[name=valor]").val() || 0;
   var descontos = $("input[name=descontos]").val() || 0;
   var juros = $("input[name=juros]").val() || 0;

   valor_cobrado = (parseFloat(valor) - parseFloat(descontos)) + parseFloat(juros);
   $("#valor_cobrado").val(parseFloat(valor_cobrado));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="descontos" placeholder="descontos">
<br>
<input type="text" name="juros" placeholder="juros">
<br>
<input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="valor">
<br>
<input type="text" id="valor_cobrado" disabled placeholder="valor cobrado">
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas como eu coloco mais de um campo chamando o blur?

Comment: De várias formas... coloca uma classe nos inputs e faz `$(".nome_da_classe").blur(...`